# Motion towards something or someone (w/ or w/o entering) using different prepositions

Tags: грамматика

I'm a little confused what the difference between `в/на + accusative` and `к + dative`, when constructing a sentence to approach/move towards/motion towards something. Specifically, in the below two examples, number 1.) for preposition к and number 2.) for preposition в.

As @Arioch answers, is it just that they both mean a motion towards something but that в means that the something was entered? (I realize he/she basically answered my question, but to keep it viable for a question that others may use I kept it worded as a question).

---

From a suggestion in comments,

For preposition к,

```
к • (+ dative case)

1.) to, toward 

к дому — to the house

к бра́ту ― to (my) brother

ко мне — to me

2.) (time): by, for

ко вторнику — by Tuesday, for Tuesday
```

and for preposition в,

```
в •

1.) (location) in, at, on (+ prepositional case)

Он в теа́тре ― He’s at (in) the theater.

2.) (direction) to, into (+ accusative case)

Он идёт в теа́тр ― He’s going to (into) the theater.

3.) (time) at, in, on (+ accusative case)

в три часа́ ― at three o’clock

в пя́тницу ― on Friday

4.) per

три ра́за в день ― three times per day
```

(Courtesy of www.Wiktionary.org)

Comment: Could you please add a couple examples to clarify your question? Thanks!

Comment: What are the difficulties? These are prepositions with different meanings.

Comment: yes, there are distinctions, and they are pretty much covered by the examples you posted. The way it is now, your question is pretty vague. Are you having troubles choosing the preposition for any specific phrase?

Comment: "В" = "in", "into". It means you finally end withIN, INside some place or process.
 - - - - - 
"К" = "to" but not "into". It means you finally come close, but you remain separated, not overlapping in space, just close enough to communicate, work together, etc.
 - - - - - 
Wanting a (rather rude) rule of thumb? Imagine a wife telling her husband "come to me" or "come into me". Grok the difference of processes implied? Same here.

Comment: @Arioch if you make it an answer I'll accept it. And for others I reworded it so that it may remain a viable question others may stumble across, if it is not to be removed that is.

Comment: @nate it was originally meant to be, but when I finished it - the question was already closed and no answers can be created for closed questions. So I just copied it as a comment.

Comment: @Arioch it is open to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"В" = "in" (or "into"). It means you finally end withIN, INside some place or process.

"К" = "to" (but without "into"). It means you finally come close to some anchor, but you remain separated, not overlapping in space, just close enough to communicate, work together, etc.

Wanting a (rather rude) rule of thumb? Imagine a wife telling her husband "come to me" or "come into me".

See the differences between the two processes implied? Both "geospatial" difference (how close/far and how distinctly/vaguely end point is positioned), some vague interconnection/intimacy/weaving difference, ability/inability of several actors finishing the same process at the same time, etc.

That i believe would hold the same with most cases of using those movement/process prepositions.